# Laradock multiprogets Lumen 404

Tags: docker, nginx, lumen, nginx-config, laradock

I created an application with lumen through laradock, for now it's just one then there will be more. This is precisely why I chose this configuration https://laradock.io/getting-started/#B.

The main folder is MicroservicesPHP, under which laradock is located, and at the same level, the folder for the blog (the application in Lumen).

MicroservicesPHP/laradock
MicroservicesPHP/blog

in the laradock .ENV APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=../

then I went to the laradock/nginx/sites/ folder and created a blog.test based on the laravel.conf.example

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name blog.test;
    root /var/www/blog/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/blog_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/blog_access.log;
}
```

then I went here C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and added host

127.0.0.2 blog.test

I restart with command: docker-compose up -d nginx mysql

I go to the browser: http://blog.test/

404 Not Found nginx

Comment: The location of your blog and the location of your laradock are important, can you update your original post with that information

Comment: @UnderDog 
The main folder is MicroservicesPHP, under which laradock is located, and at the same level, the folder for the blog (the application in Lumen).

Comment: c:\projects\blog is my blog directory, c:\laradock is my laradock directory.My path is APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=../projects/ but since it's on windows you'll have to set an extra setting. Allllways be specific and keep updating your original post. Your 404 error is because that blog directory cannot be found. Open up your workspace container and see if you can find your blog directory there.